# How do I rejoin a wireless network as though I were a new machine?

Tags: networking, ip-address, wireless

For a classification project I'm trying to generate a large list of dynamic IP addresses from a single wireless network. However, the only way I've been able to generate these addresses is by connecting a physically new machine to the network, as the wireless network remembers each machine (and so, whenever one machine rejoins the network the IP address remains the same).

For the sake of brevity, I've been looking for a way of automating the process; technically, all I need to do is find a way to simulate being a "new" machine. This way, it would be far easier to generate a list of IP addresses assigned by a single wireless network.

I've had a great deal of trouble finding out how to do this, and it is very possible I may misunderstand how a wireless network assigns IP addresses, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Wireless networks don't assign IP addresses. Have you read about [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol)? Then, knowing that, you can simply ask the DHCP administrator. No need to do it empirically.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this.

Comment: This is very helpful, but I need to clarify that I'm trying to test the feasibility of "guessing" the protocol, or at least building a perceptron learning vector that could guess if an address "came from" this network. Consequently, I need to take an empirical approach.

Answer (score -1):

<sub>(continuing from the comments above...)</sub>

As it turns out, there's no fancy machine learning necessary at all. You can get all the information you need by connecting just once. When you connect to an IP network and are assigned an address, you get both an *address* and a *subnet mask* (look it up if you're not familiar with the terms). Given these, a straightforward snippet of bitwise arithmetic will show you whether another address is part of the same network or not:

```
if ((my_address & subnet_mask) == (unknown_address & subnet_mask)) { ...
```

where `unknown_address` is the address you're testing. (This expression can be simplified a bit by applying boolean simplification rules, but this is a form where it's obvious what is happening.)

For example, if you are assigned:

```
address: 192.168.11.22
subnet: 255.255.255.0
```

then any other address is part of the same network if it starts with `192.168.11.`. Again, the person who set up the network has very deliberately made these choices.

This very much reminds me of the so-called [Barometer question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer_question), where one of the possible answers is "trading the barometer to the building's superintendent in return for the information wanted".